# Vivado: Block Design sub module

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq

I'm working on a Video processing project with Vivado 2015.2 on a Zynq device.

My block design starts to get huge and hard to read. As I have several times the same pipline implemented, I would like to make some kind of submodule (take some IP and connect them together in a separate block diagram). Is it possible to do that? Can I use a (sub-) block diagram several times in the main diagram?

Comment: Image quality not good enough. Upload a seperate one directly to imgur.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is package sub modules as IP. Then you can use the IP as sub modules in a bigger design. The problem is that you can only package a whole block diagram. What you have to do is create a new block diagram, insert the blocks making a sub-module, package it as an IP and then add it to the main design. Repeat for all sub modules.

Created IPs can be used several times in another block diagram.

[This](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/ug949-vivado-design-methodology.pdf) Explains the process in detail.